# Code First conventions confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, html.dropdownlistfor

Models:

```
public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Podcast
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

The Podcast table has the StatusId column, and this column is a foreign key. In this case I've got the following error message: `Invalid column name 'Status_Id'.` Why? - Many times I faced that articles with such examples. This is the first question.
Ok, no problem - i've added an underscore character to these columns: Sttaus_Id and so on. 
Now it seems that everything works fine, but when I modify my model by the following way:

```
public class Podcast
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Status_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

Now I get the following error: `Invalid column name 'Status_Id1'.`
Why? I can't use the DropDownListFor helper without these xx_id properies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that you have created your DB first and created a column named StatusId for your FK reference but you haven't told EF that you are using a non-default column name for your FK.

the following will give you the structure you are after (ps i agree with your naming convention i personally dislike the _ in fk ids)

```
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Podcast> Podcasts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Status> Status { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Podcast>().HasOptional(p => p.Status)
                .WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.StatusId);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class Status
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Podcast
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int? StatusId { get; set; }
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The convention at least for the foreign key field is table name + field name, so in your case StatusId without the underscore. But I'm not sure why it says `invalid column name Status_Id1`.

Remove the underscore, and try again. If you still get an error message, please make an edit to your question with the results.

Comment: This is actually incorrect, the default convention is tablename_id for FK references.

Comment: Im using EF4.3, and are using foreign keys without underscore and I have done no changes to the default convention. So I have table called Carrier, and a second table called MobileUnit. The second table has a property `public Carrier Carrier` and a property `public in CarrierId` and they both map just fine to the Carrier table without any extra configuration.

Comment: Yeah EF will guess that your FK is as you have specified but its not the default behavior, run this and take a look at the DB it builds, https://gist.github.com/2708741. In the above example you could just put in a FK property and it will guess it but im a big fan of being explicit when you arent following the actual convention. In addition the above will work for any name you give to the FK property.

Comment: @Luke - I didn't know, and inside the book Programming Entity Framework Code First they use this as the convention throughout the book. You are saying that it would work for any name? I didn't understand what you meant there. I have three foreign keys in the class, and they all get mapped to the correct tables so I guess it matters what I call them. So the point is just that since EF does not find Carrier_Id, but finds CarrierId, it picks CarrierId instead?

Comment: The property EF will generate by default is Carrier_Id. However in your case as it has seen that you have CarrierId as a property on you class it guesses/infers that it must be the FK for Carrier (however this isn't the actual default property naming convention, just one EF understands and many people including myself use). The issue with the OPs code is that he didnt have a property with the default name in his code, but instead had a non-default one in the DB so EF created Status_Id for him behind the scenes (using default naming) but couldnt find that property in the DB

Comment: Ahhh, now I understand what you are trying to tell me here. If I don't put the variable myself, then in the database it will be created with an underscore. Then your points are read an understood :)

Comment: Yeah the default is with an _ (and that will work everywhere) but its kinda hotwired to work in basic cases without the _