# Navigation Property Issue With Entity Framework (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My database structure looks like this: Categories table, Questions table and Answers table. Questions have a CategoryID, and Answers have an AnswerID. When trying to access the navigation property "Answers" in my view, I receive the following error:

> "'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code" Which
>   is accompanied by:
>
> "Invalid column name 'Question_ID'."

Here's what my classes look like:

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

For Question:

```
public class Question
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And for Answer:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Correct { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

And my Database uses exactly the same field names, with foreign keys applied. I have tried so many variations on the names, including changing the foreign keys to 'Question_ID'and 'Category_ID' but no luck. I've also tried this solution: [Code First conventions confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614377/code-first-conventions-confusion) but it didn't work. Anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: How did you generate the database and/or the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is with your answer class.  Try this...

```
public class Answer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Correct { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Question")]
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```